# Eloquent Many to Many Attach Function sending a Null ID

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following code which is attempting to attach a product to a product_slot.

```
$product_slot = new ProductSlot;
$product_slot = $product_slot->where('type', $slot['id'])->first();

$product = new Product;
$product = $product->where('type', (String)$allowed_product)->first();

$product->productSlots()->sync([$product_slot->product_slot_id]);
```

I can do a `getAttributes()` and both return the following:

```
array (size=6)
  'product_slot_id' => int 1
  'type' => string 'breakfastplatter1' (length=17)
  'default_product_id' => string 'bigbfhotcakebiscplat_3590' (length=25)
  'allow_empty' => int 0
  'created_at' => string '2016-08-17 19:04:41' (length=19)
  'updated_at' => string '2016-08-17 19:04:41' (length=19)

array (size=7)
  'product_id' => int 185
  'type' => string 'bigbfhotcakebiscplat_3590' (length=25)
  'label' => string 'Big Breakfast with Hot Cakes (Biscuit)' (length=38)
  'min_option_slots' => int 0
  'max_option_slots' => int 0
  'created_at' => string '2016-08-17 19:05:40' (length=19)
  'updated_at' => string '2016-08-17 19:05:40' (length=19)
```

Here is the Product Model relationship:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['type', 'label', 'min_option_slots', 'max_option_slots'];

    public function productSlots()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\ProductSlot');
    }
}
```

However, when I try to sync these models together I get the following error.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'product_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `product_product_slot`
>   (`product_id`, `product_slot_id`) values (, 1))

Comment: Sure. I'll update it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using custom primary key names instead of the Laravel convention of using `id` as the primary key. Try adding this to your models:

```
class Product {
    public $primaryKey = 'product_id';
}

class ProductSlot {
    public $primaryKey = 'product_slot_id';
}
```

Also note that if you don't follow Laravel conventions, you also sometimes need to specify the non-standard primary keys when defining relationship functions:

```
public function productSlots()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\ProductSlot', 'product_slot_id', 'product_id');
}
```